# FFImageLoading ErrorCommand invokes all instances

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

I am trying to use `FFImageLoading` in a `ListView` using only XAML and a view model. For each item in the list i have a model and I want to trap when an image fails to load and update a label thats associated with the image in the same model.

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage
        DownsampleToViewSize="true"
        RetryCount="0"
        ErrorCommand="{Binding ImageLoadError}"
        IsVisible="{Binding HasAttachement}"
        Source="{Binding Attachment}">
</ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

I thought adding an `ErrorCommand` handler thats bound in my model would work except the command is being invoked for *every instance* of my model and not just the instance where the image loading fails

```
ImageLoadError = new Command((e) =>
{
   Debug.WriteLine($"Image load error Text is {Text}");
});
```

The above command handler is invoked for every instance of my model and not just the instance attached to the failed image.

How can i get notifications of loading errors to only the instance of my model thats associated with the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see on the FFImageLoading Wiki/Documentation at the **Events** section ([FFImaleLoading Events](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API#events)) there is an event for 'Errors' on which you can listen to.

> Error
>
> Occurs after every image loading error. Returns: Exception

Try to subscribe to this event and it should return only those instances which cannot be loaded.